# Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.1.1) how to get friends

Tags: facebook

```
try {

  $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

  error_log($e);

}
```

Shows :Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in C:\wamp\www\fb\facebook_php_sdk\src\base_facebook.php on line 1106

Comment: _“please help!”_ – Please read documentation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have access token for this operation.
First you request for access token like this:

```
$my_access_token=$facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Then you can request for friend list like this:

```
try {

$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends',array('access_token'=>$my_access_token));
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

error_log($e);
}
```

This might work. I this works,then accept this answer!
Happy Coding!